# Empty result when comparing variables

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I am currently writing a simple VB Script for data validation for an internal application.  Unfortunately, the result is returning an empty value when I expected a numeric result.  The script is below.

```
Dim Result, QuantityPerInnerPack, QuantityPerIndividualUnit
Result = 1
QuantityPerInnerPack = 2
QuantityPerIndividualUnit = 250
If QuantityPerInnerPack <- 1 Then
Result = QuantityPerIndividualUnit
Else
Result = QuantitytPerInnerPack
End If
WScript.Echo Result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your else statement you have:

```
Result = QuantitytPerInnerPack
```

You have a typo in there with that extra t:

```
Result = QuantityPerInnerPack
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your response.  Horrible post on my part.